# Javascript jQuery function does not define variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript and am trying to run a JavaScript/jQuery function, where Firefox gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: latitude is not defined
    getHighLow http://localhost:5000/static/weatherballoon.js:54
    <anonymous> http://localhost:5000/static/weatherballoon.js:63
weatherballoon.js:54:5
```

The code being referenced is below.

````
function getHighLow(){
    $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + cityID + '&key=' + geocodekey, function(data){
        latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        longitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    });
    $.getJSON('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat='+ latitude +'&lon='+ longitude +'&exclude={alerts,minutely,hourly}&appid='+ owmkey, function(data){
        var tempmin = Math.round(data.daily[0].temp.min) + '&deg;';
        var tempmax = Math.round(data.daily[0].temp.min) + '&deg;';
        document.getElementById('tempmin').innerHTML = tempmin;
        document.getElementById('tempmax').innerHTML = tempmax;
    });
}```
````

Comment: use ```var``` keyword left next to longitude

Comment: @UmairMubeen I have attempted to use var and the error still persists

Comment: neste your requests, the are on the same "height"/level. Like @barmar did in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON()` is asynchronous. You're trying to use the variables before they're set in the callback.

You need to perform the second `getJSON` in the first one's callback function.

```js
function getHighLow() {
  $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + cityID + '&key=' + geocodekey, function(data) {
    const latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    const longitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    $.getJSON('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude + '&exclude={alerts,minutely,hourly}&appid=' + owmkey, function(data) {
      var tempmin = Math.round(data.daily[0].temp.min) + '&deg;';
      var tempmax = Math.round(data.daily[0].temp.min) + '&deg;';
      document.getElementById('tempmin').innerHTML = tempmin;
      document.getElementById('tempmax').innerHTML = tempmax;
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

````js
function getHighLow(){
var latitude=0;
var longitude=0;
    $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + cityID + '&key=' + geocodekey, function(data){
        latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        longitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    });
    $.getJSON('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat='+ latitude +'&lon='+ longitude +'&exclude={alerts,minutely,hourly}&appid='+ owmkey, function(data){
        var tempmin = Math.round(data.daily[0].temp.min) + '&deg;';
        var tempmax = Math.round(data.daily[0].temp.min) + '&deg;';
        document.getElementById('tempmin').innerHTML = tempmin;
        document.getElementById('tempmax').innerHTML = tempmax;
    });
}```
````

Comment: This will prevent the error message, but won't put the returned values into the second URL because of asynchrony.